# Parse a JSON list without a Deserializer

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, json-deserialization

My goal is to be able to take in any input and add data to an existing database with it. How can I access the 'name' & 'usernum' properties without specifically declaring a Deserializer (because the class will change based on the query)?

```
{  
   "MessageType":"Sql",
   "SqlCommandString":"select [name],[usernum] from x.dbo.y",
   "DbReply":[  
      {  
         "name":"xx",
         "usernum":22
      },
      {  
         "name":"yy",
         "usernum":23
      }
   ]
}
```

C# to deserialize the JSON:

```
public class SqlReply
{
    public string MessageType { get; set; }
    public string SqlCommandString { get; set; }
    public List<object> DbReply { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like rather than deserializing it, you want to [parse](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse_1.htm) it and access the properties manually?

Comment: Like this? https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm

Comment: Make `DbReply` a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`.

Comment: without specifically declaring a "Deserializer", do you mean the `SqlReply` class?

Comment: you could deserialise to `dynamic`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Json.Linq`:

```
var json = @"{  
   ""MessageType"":""Sql"",
   ""SqlCommandString"":""select [name],[usernum] from x.dbo.y"",
   ""DbReply"":[  
      {  
         ""name"":""xx"",
         ""usernum"":22
      },
      {  
         ""name"":""yy"",
         ""usernum"":23
      }
   ]
}";

var sql = JToken.Parse(json);
var replies = sql["DbReply"]
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Name = (string)x["name"],
        UserNum = (int)x["usernum"],
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could do this using the `JavaScriptSerializer` class that is defined in `System.Web.Extensions.dll`. You could either deserialize the JSON data to into a `dynamic` object:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
dynamic obj = serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(object));
foreach (var reply in obj["DbReply"])
{
    string name = reply["name"];
    int usernum = reply["usernum"];
}
```

Or into a `DbReply`:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
SqlReply obj = serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(SqlReply)) as SqlReply;
foreach (dynamic reply in obj.DbReply)
{
    string name = reply["name"];
    int usernum = reply["usernum"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @stuartd suggestion in the comments I would up using [parse](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse_1.htm) then parsing the string manually